# Set relative path for Capl function sysExecCmd

Tags: capl

**I have following line of code. I want to set relative path instead of hardcoded path as is presently set in 2nd argument below-**

```c
sysExecCmd("Unlock_Ecu.bat","","D:\\Program Files\\ToolPath");
```

**Should be replaced as:**

```c
sysExecCmd("Unlock_Ecu.bat","","...\\ToolPath");
```

**How can I do it in sysExecCmd function of Capl ?**

Comment: Thanks @Blisskarthik for edits. Any suggestion for this problem as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do it as listed below:

```c
variables
{
  char absPath[256];   // Holds Abs Path for current CFG file
  // Relative Path for ToolPath folder
  char ToolPath[100]= "\\ToolPath\\";
}

on preStart
{
  /* Get Abs path of current config file */
  GetUserFilePath("", absPath, 256);
  Exec_Batch();
}

void Exec_Batch()
{
  /* Get Absolute Path for executing Bat file */
  char absToolPath[256];
  strncat(absToolPath, absPath, strlen(absPath));
  strncat(absToolPath, ToolPath, strlen(absToolPath) + strlen(ToolPath)); 

  write("Executing Batch File");

  sysExecCmd("Unlock_Ecu.bat","",absToolPath);

  write("Finished execution of Batch File");
}
```

Comment: Hey @Vaibhav, how are you? Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

From the `sysExecCmd` documentation (emphasis mine):

> **To avoid absolute paths** in CAPL code and to be independent of the execution platform, proceed as follows:
>
> Add the application to be started to the User Files in CANoe Options dialog. 
>   At application call the absolute path can be resolved with the CAPL function `GetUserFilePath`.

Example:

```c
char absPath[256];
GetUserFilePath("Unlock_Ecu.bat", absPath, 256);
SysExecCmd(absPath, "");
```